# argument of function does not get a value

Tags: anylogic

I would like to change the colour of my AGV. There are three different types of AGV and each AGV should have a special colour.

For this, there is a function to which I pass an int between 0 and 2. (For the function I have defined an argument called input, which is int).

The problem is that the number passed between 0 and 2 is not stored in the argument. Instead, the default value 0 is always assumed '. The consequence of this is that I always fall into the first case in the switch loop.

Can anyone help me?[image: funciton of main]

[image: function get Color]

Comment: Use a traceln before calling the function (but with the argument you are passing in) and in the function itself (`traceln(input));`). You will see that there is nothing wrong in the function but that you are always passing `0` to the function. In other words: The functions and their arguments work, it is somewhere in your model that you are calling it wrongly (hard to say where as you are not showing how you call it)